# Timestamps of start and end of month in java

Tags: java, datetime, unix-timestamp, java-time

I want a program in which I give month and year and the program should return start and end timestamp of the month.

For example, if I pass January and 2011 to the method it will return 
start=1293840000
end = 1296518400

Is there any way to do this.

Comment: What time zone do you want? Or no time zone offset ([UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
long startDate;
long endDate;

private void calculateMonthStartAndEndTime(int month, int year){
//create the first date of month
Calendar mycal = new GregorianCalendar(year,month, 1);
startDate = mycal.getTimeInMillis();

// Get the number of days in that month which actually gives the last date.
int lastDate = mycal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
mycal = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, lastDate);
endDate = mycal.getTimeInMillis();
}
```

Comment: In comparison to the OP's example, this has an "out by one" error.  Better just to add one month, than to use `getActualMaximum`.

Comment: And as well as being off by one (that is, it gives an interval of 30 days, not 31 days for January); it doesn't take account of the time zone correctly, so unless your timezone is UTC, you won't get the same answer as the OP's example, even for the start of the month.

Comment: This answer ignores the issue of time zone. Your results will vary from computer to computer, or even on one computer if the time zone setting is altered, or even in one JVM is the default time zone is reset by any other running Java code.

Answer (score 3):

## Joda-Time

This kind of work is much easier using the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library.

## Time Zone

You should specify a time zone, rather than rely on default of the JVM/host computer. Seems that you want UTC (no time zone offset), so your code should say so explicitly.

## Half-Open

Also, getting the last moment of a day is tricky. In theory, there is always another divisible fraction of second before the start of the next day. While you want to resolve to seconds (Unix item), two of the common Java libraries (java.util.Date/.Calendar and Joda-Time) use milliseconds, and the new java.time library in Java 8 resolves to nanoseconds. Instead, date-time work is often done using the "half-open" approach where a span of time is defined with the beginning to be *inclusive* and the ending to be *exclusive*. So "January" runs from `first moment of January 1` to `first moment of February 1`.

## Example

Here is some example code in Joda-Time 2.3.

```
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.UTC;
DateTime start = new DateTime( 2011, DateTimeConstants.JANUARY, 1, 0, 0, 0, timeZone).withTimeAtStartOfDay();
DateTime stop = start.plusMonths( 1 );
```

You might find the [Interval](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html) class interesting for related work.

```
Interval january2011 = new Interval( start, stop );
```

Convert to seconds, from milliseconds.

```
long secondsStart = start.getMillis()/1000L;
long secondsStop = stop.getMillis()/1000L;
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the `Calendar` class:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html

Answer (score 1):

**Update with the Java 8 answer**

(Java 8 includes a new time library based on JodaTime):

```
    ZoneId timeZone = ZoneId.of("US/Eastern");
    //ZoneId timeZone = ZoneOffset.UTC;

    LocalDate march1985 = LocalDate.of(2017, Month.MARCH, 1);
    long beginningOfMarch = march1985.atStartOfDay(timeZone)
            .toInstant()
            .toEpochMilli();

    LocalDate april1985 = march1985.plus(1, ChronoUnit.MONTHS);
    long endOfMarch = april1985.atStartOfDay(timeZone)
            .toInstant()
            .toEpochMilli();
```

**Time Zones**

The "start of the month" is a function of the time zone, so in this case I've shown how to do it in Eastern time.  These *java.time* classes handle DST automatically, so, for example, if you do the year 2017 instead of 1985, you'll find the difference is 743 hours instead of 744, because in 1985 DST took place in April.